# Cartoon/anime with spherical androids that had limbs but could contract into a complete sphere

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

There is this cartoon (or anime I can’t really tell) that I would watch like 9-10 years ago but can’t remember the name of.

Basically it was about these spherical androids, with limbs and all, but they could contract into a full sphere and move around at full speed. The protagonist I think was a red sphere android, the last of its kind for some reason and people didn’t really like him. There was also this other guy with his eye patched put. Also, the roads and stuff were all over the place; as in bridges and what not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [*RollBots*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1174020/) (2009)

> Flip (voiced by Sam Vincent) is the newest member of the Spin City Police Department -- and the fastest of all the ROLLBOTS in town. These rolling robotic spheres zip and flip down the city’s track-like streets, sprouting arms, legs, and heads when they're at rest. Excited, eager, and energetic, Flip makes up for his lack of experience with enough bravery and enthusiasm to give him an edge when he takes on the evil Vertex (Colin Murdock) and his henchmen.
>
> <sub>[Common Sense Media, RollBots](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/tv-reviews/rollbots)</sub>

[image: RollBots poster]

There is a [wiki](https://rollbots.fandom.com/wiki/Rollbots_Wiki) for it which turns up [Capitan Pounder](https://rollbots.fandom.com/wiki/Capitan_Pounder) who would appear to be the character with only one eye.

[image: Captain Pounder showing he only has one eye]

---

I found this by Googling `tv cartoon "spherical robot"` on the Images tab which turned up [this page](http://www.vancouversun.com/story_print.html?id=1256993&sponsor=) because of the image. The image seemed promising so a few quick searches on *RollBots* and skimming a few episodes and it seemed to match quite well.

Comment: I'm not sure if the red character is called Flip as that review mentions or Spin as that is what the wiki calls him.

Comment: YESSS THANK YOU THAT IS THE ONE